# How to use entropy as method of split In decision tree - R Programming

Tags: r, decision-tree

While building a decision tree, I intend to use entropy as the splitting criteria. 
In the package `rpart`, there is the only profession for GINI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use C5.0 Decision trees which use Entropy as the splitting criterion.

```
install.packages("C50")
```

The `C5.0` function is used for model building.